# Implementing an API key to restrict access to webservice URL

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, api, security

Essentially I want to restrict raw access to a webservice which my app connects to. Essentially, the app is dragging data from 'http://apis.example.com/webservice'. By simply clicking on the link anyone can view the information as it's open.

I'd like to add an API key which I will code into the app.

My question is simply, how do I set up an API key to prevent people accessing the webservice without appending the key? The data is held in MySQL and a PHP script displays the data.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API key is just a fancy term for a password between machines. All you have to do is think of a random string, send it along with your request, and have the responding server expect the same string or refuse to provide a response.

For example, if your API key is the ever secure `password123`, you could have a request like this:

http://apis.example.com/webservice?key=password123

and have your server-side code set up like so:

```
if (!isset($_GET['key']) || ($_GET['key'] !== 'password123')) {
    die('You shall not pass!');
} else {
    // do your magic
}
```

This will only run the meat of your API script for those who possess the key.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Having a fixed sting is better than nothing, but anyone inspecting the data can sniff it and steal your key.

You could implement a challenge response setup by coding a secret key into your app, have the app make a request to the server and in response the server returns a random string.

The app performs a calculation on the string using the secret key as a factor and returns the result to the server.

The server has the secret key so knows the result to expect, if it matches then it serves the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use API Gateway , there are many opensource solutions  ( Kong , Apigee etc ) available which will sit in front of your API and will provide security and many more things to your API.